# How Does One Execute a Command Line Under a Visual Studio Python Environment?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-2017

I've cloned a git repository with source for a Python module that must be installed with the command line:

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

As I'm developing with Visual Studio 2017, it seems the only safe option is to execute this under the VS's default `python` environment, which, in my configuration is 3.6.  However, running the `Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.5.1` doesn't recognize `pip3`.  It doesn't even recognize `python`.

What is the secret?

PS: I discovered that I can `Install from requirements.txt` (see `Managing Required Packages` at [Python Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-environments)):

`View -> Solution Explorer -> Python Environments -> **right click** on Python 3.6 (64-bit)(global default) -> Install from requirements.txt`

But then it pops up with an "Output" window that simply says `Failed to install`.

(Good grief!)

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01538130-9af0-4dc9-9331-c84b30d580d3/visual-studio-2017-installation-not-showing-python-tools?forum=vssetup), you can try the [Visual Studio preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/)

> - Install the "Visual Studio 2017 Preview" from https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview.
>     NOTE: This Preview channel is distinct from the released version of Visual Studio 2017, and contains features under development for future Visual Studio 2017 updates, including Python support.
> - In the Preview installer, select the Web & Cloud > Python Development workload:
>     [image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/media/installation-python-workload.png]